# Agregar formulario en un <section> por medio de un boton en C# secciones <...section...>

Tags: c#, html, asp

Buen día a todos, tengo un formulario que esta dividido en .

Quisiera saber, como al presionar un botón que se encuentra en otro (), me agregue el formulario a mi otro (), espero y me haya explicado correctamente.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<section class="content-header">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">REPORTES MENSUALES FEMSA</h3>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl_fechas" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-4">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Unidad_Operativa" runat="server" style ="width: auto"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-4">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Zonas" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div class="row"> //ESTE ES EL BOTÓN QUE GENERARIA EL LLAMADO AL FORMULARIO
        <asp:Button ID="genera_reporte" runat="server" Text="Generar"/>

    </div>       
</section>

<section class ="container">

    //aqui me gustaria que apareciera el otro formulario.
</section>
```

La plantilla máster, esta desarrollada en Bootstrap, esta dividida en secciones, cada sección tiene contenedores y a su vez tiene párrafos. En un formulario tengo un gráfico, el cual, quisiera agregarlo al presionar un botón que se encuentra sobre una sección, es decir sobre la misma página, mandarlo a llamar al presionar el botón.

Comment: Debes formular y explicar mejor tu pregunta y porfavor coloca algo de codigo para ver que logrado hacer hasta el momento

Comment: Quisiera entenderte para poder ayudarte. Tienes dos formularios que se podrían llamar `formA` y `formB`; en el formulario `A` tienes un botón llamado `generar_reporte` que cuando se presione debe incluir el fomulario `B` en el elemento `<section class ="container">` de tu formulario `A`. Mi pregunta es, ¿En que lado lo deseas hacer, [lado cliente o lado servidor](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/239.php)? ¿Se podría usar un [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp)?

Comment: Si es decir, hay un formulario donde se integran todas las gráficas  que es la (pantalla principal). En ella he creado secciones, en esas secciones, como lo muestro en la pregunta, tengo dividida cada una de mis contenedores. En donde muestro los comentarios, ahí me gustaría agregar el objeto gráfica (me estoy refiriendo a un contenedor) que se agregaría solo al presionar el botón que se encuentra en una clase row. Los comentarios se encuentran en la pregunta. Espero me haya dado a entender lo suficiente para no confundirlos mas. Es del lado del servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Hola tienes que crear un scritp en javascript

```
<script>
function otro_section() {
    $("#nombrediv").append('<section class="container">');
    $("#nombrediv").append('<input name="nose" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nose"/>');
    $("#nombrediv").append('</section>');
}
</script>
```

y al botón tendrías que asignarle la función.

```
<input class="btn btn-login" type="button" value="Otro servicio" onclick="otro_servicio()"/>
```

ojo el hace el importe de la nueva linea en un DIV o SECTION que tenga el id nombrediv o el que le pongas.

```
<div id="nombrediv">

//example

</div>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muy buena idea, muchas grax.

Comment: de nada, cualquier cosa avisa, si te sirvió recuerda calificar la publicación haciendo clic en la flecha hacia arriba.